# What's another way of writing this jQuery so Chrome doesn't object to it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I've tracked down a syntax error that happens in Chrome but not in Firefox or IE.

It has to do with this expression (taken from [this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form)):

```
var name = $( "#name" ),
            email = $( "#email" ),
            password = $( "#password" ),
            allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
            tips = $( ".validateTips" );
```

**What's another way of writing this that makes Chrome happy?**

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you just need to use a variable other than `name`, like this:

```
var something = $( "#name" ),
    email = $( "#email" ),
    password = $( "#password" ),
    allFields = $( [] ).add( something ).add( email ).add( password ),
    tips = $( ".validateTips" );
```

Also, you can shorten it a bit - no need for that extra empty jQuery object:

```
var something = $("#name"),
    email = $("#email"),
    password = $("#password"),
    allFields = something.add(email).add(password),
    tips = $(".validateTips");
```

Comment: Why is the variable name `name` a problem inside that function? I'm not immediately seeing it.

Comment: **Thank you** - I just realised that `.add()` creates a **new** jQuery object. I've always wondered why my `$().add(.....)`s never worked. How silly of me, should have read the docos more carefully!

Comment: @T.J. - I'm not sure actually, but it appears to be a named object in Chrome...maybe a dev build issue? I'm not sure how far back it dates.

Comment: @Nick: That would be very bad, `name` isn't exactly an uncommon variable name. :-) Where did you run across that? Doesn't appear to be in the current release build for Linux (8.0.552.215), at least not in a simple test: http://jsbin.com/exiya3

Comment: @T.J. - What do you get here? http://jsbin.com/exiya3/2 I get a string type in Chrome 9.0.597.16 on Windows

Comment: @Nick: Of course you do (and so do I) -- `name` is a property of `window`. :-) http://jsbin.com/exiya3/3 http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#window But that doesn't mean you can't shadow it (like a bunch of other `window` properties) in a function: http://jsbin.com/exiya3/4 I get "string" from your original jsbin on Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and even IE6 -- as I should. :-)

Comment: @T.J. - I agree, but in this case it's breaking...definitely appears to be a bug in Chrome, at least in the dev version...I can't offer a rational explanation for a bug :)

Comment: @Nick: *"I can't offer a rational explanation for a bug."* Indeed. :-) Do you have a failing test case you can post somewhere? I'd like to see if it fails in the release build. No biggie if you don't, just curious. (Or did my http://jsbin.com/exiya3/4 fail for you?)